# Probelm with executing a shell command in Emacs

Tags: linux, emacs

I am using XEmacs 23.

I tried to execute a shell command by `M-! cmd RET` but it did not work.

`M-!` does not turn up in the microbuffer no matter how many times I press `Alt+!`.

But if I go to `Tools` menu and select `Shell Command...` option then it writes `M-!` to the microbuffer and everything works fine.

What is the problem here?

NOTE: I am using XMonad window manager. Is it affecting key bindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either <kbd>Escape</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd> to enter `M-!`. If <kbd>Escape</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd> but not <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd>, it's probably because your window manager has rebound that key combination. Try typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd>. If this shows “M-! runs …”, the key combination is bound to the indicated command. If the “Describe key” prompt just sits there, it means the key isn't getting to Emacs at all. Use <kbd>Escape</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd> as a workaround or change your window manager binding.

Answer (score 1):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `shell-command`, it should say something like:

```
shell-command is an interactive compiled Lisp function.

It is bound to <f10>, M-!, <menu-bar> <tools> <shell>.

[...]
```

If `M-!` doesn't appear in that list then it's an issue about `XEmacs`: try to rebind it in your `.emacs`.

Otherwise it may be that <kbd>Alt</kbd> is used by `XMonad` as main key, I suggest you to use the Windows (super) key for that.